# Cannot get reactjs-admin-lte to work with my reactjs project

Tags: reactjs, adminlte

I'm pretty new to this react/nodejs/bootstrap affair. I'm trying to make use of the reactjs-adminlte theme for bootstrap. I can get bootstrap widgets to work fine, such as buttons, but having trouble with this theme. The error I get is

```
React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

My code is as follows

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">



    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.
      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!-- Ionicons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
        <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini ">
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->



   <script src="/dist/js/vendors.js"></script>
  <script src="/dist/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import  Sidebar  from 'adminlte-reactjs';

class App extends Component {

  render() {


    return (
      <div className="App">

        <Sidebar>

        </Sidebar>     

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Would love to know why i cant get the Sidebar to display. Its probably something simple that im missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should change:

`import  Sidebar  from 'adminlte-reactjs';`

to

`import  {Sidebar}  from 'adminlte-reactjs';`

or:

```
import  adminlteReactjs  from 'adminlte-reactjs';

let Sidebar  = adminlteReactjs.Sidebar;

<Sidebar>
</Sidebar>
```